# Why is my clickNumber variable not holding selected dom Element?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a counter that attaches a click event handler to the increment button. There must be 2 functions and the variables must be declared outside the functions. Why is it not able to read the value of `clickNumber`? If I declare the value inside the increment function it works.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Counter</title>
    <script src="counter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <button id="increment">Increment</button>
    <p id="counter">Counter = 0</p>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var counter = 0;
var clickNumber = document.getElementById("counter");



function getElementBtnIncrement() {

    document.getElementById("increment").addEventListener("click",increment,false);

}


function increment(){
    counter++;
    clickNumber.innerHTML = "Count = " + counter;
}



window.addEventListener( "load", getElementBtnIncrement, false );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `counter.js` script is being loaded on the document `head`, i.e. before the `#counter` element is created. This means that this code:

```
var clickNumber = document.getElementById("counter");
```

will result in `clickNumber` being `null` (since the element doesn't exist yet).

You can fix this by assigning the `clickNumber` value once the DOM is loaded:

```
var counter = 0;
var clickNumber; // still declared outside, but the value is assigned later



function getElementBtnIncrement() {

    document.getElementById("increment").addEventListener("click",increment,false);

}


function increment(){
    counter++;
    clickNumber.innerHTML = "Count = " + counter;
}



window.addEventListener( "load", function() {
  clickNumber = document.getElementById("counter");
  getElementBtnIncrement();
}, false );
```